# Returning a Generic container from a Set of Dictionaries

Tags: c++, templates

I have a collection of dictionaries (std::maps) which store generic containers Foo together with a unique ID. Given such a unique ID, I would like to return the corresponding container. But I do not know before hand in which dict the Foo object with a given ID is stored, so something along line of the following:

```
#include <map>

std::map<ID, Foo<double>> mapDouble;
std::map<ID, Foo<int>>    mapInt;


template <class T>
Foo<T> getVal(ID id) {

    std::map<ID, Foo<double>>::iterator itDoub = mapDouble.find(id);
    if(itDoub != mapDouble.end()) {
       return = itDoub->second;
    }


    std::map<ID, Foo<int>>::iterator itInt = mapInt.find(id);
    if(itInt!= mapInt.end()) {
       return = itInt->second;
    }
}


void bar() {
    Foo<int> foo getVal<int>(3);
}
```

But I get the following error message

```
error: no viable conversion from 'Foo <double>' to 'Foo <int>'
```

which of course makes complete sense.
But what is the correct way of implementing this functionality?
I guess what I am implementing here is some sort of Factory.

Comment: `getVal<int>` should only search inside `mapInt`.

Comment: What should happen if key is not found ?

Comment: @Jarod42 the key is coming from an enum, so its "guaranteed" that a corresponding object is registered

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree that getVal<int> should only search inside mapInt, but I don't know how to achieve this, since I can not overload functions only by the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is no nice connection between the type parameter (`<int>`), and the member name (`mapInt`).

The solution is to find some way not to use the member - the simplest is:

```
#include <map>

typedef int ID;
template <typename T> struct Foo {};

class MapContainer {
    std::map<ID, Foo<double>> mapDouble;
    std::map<ID, Foo<int>>    mapInt;

    template <typename T> std::map<ID, Foo<T>>& getmap();

public:
    template <class T>
    Foo<T> getVal(ID id) {
        auto &map = getmap<T>();
        auto it = map.find(id);
        if(it != map.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            return Foo<T>{}; // ???
        }
    }
};

template <> std::map<ID, Foo<double>>& MapContainer::getmap() { return mapDouble; }
template <> std::map<ID, Foo<int>>& MapContainer::getmap() { return mapInt; }
```

Here, the connection between type and member name is handled by the template method specializations (`getmap`).

---

Note that this currently gives a linker error for unsupported types. You can get a slightly friendlier error message by defining the generic getmap such that it fails on instantiation.

A fiddlier but perhaps more satisfying solution (that also scales and generalizes better to more types) is to eliminate the named data members entirely, and use a generic type-to-container lookup instead. For example, a tuple of maps can be interrogated by element type instead of position (see Modern C++ Design/Loki), and Boost.Fusion provides heterogeneous sets that would do what you want.